# AngularJS + < IE11 results in crash when waiting for response from server

Tags: angularjs

I can't quite figure this out. I'm calling a WebAPI method using Angular that returns JSON. Unfortunately, and out of my control, this method takes roughly 15-20 seconds to send data back to the client.

These delays are no problem with all browsers except for anything below IE11 (i.e., 9, 10)

I've played around with several header settings. Here's an example of my code:

```
MyApp.service("ApiService", function($http, $q, $httpParamSerializerJQLike){


    var self = this;
    self.Headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "Cache-Control": "max-age=0, public"  
    };

    return({
      GetList: GetList
    });

    function GetList(settings) {

      var request = $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "My/Path",
        cache: true,
        params: settings.params,
        headers: self.Headers            
      });

      return( request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
    }

    function handleError( response ) {

      return( $q.reject(response.data) );

    }

    function handleSuccess( response ) {
      return( response.data );        
    }

  });
```

I get "Long running script" errors, among other weirdness. Most of the time I can't even click refresh. It's like it paralyzes the machine entirely.

When I test other methods that take a second or two with the same approach, it works fine.

The other aspect to this code is ng-repeat. Perhaps it's the amount of data that Angular is dealing with, DOM-related events and IE doesn't like it? But we're talking 250 or so objects in the JSON array response... and these objects are fairly big.

Any ideas as to how to pinpoint the issue? I'm hoping this will spark a flashback with someone who has dealt with it.